# .NET MAUI disabling back button globally

Tags: maui

Current code:

```
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior  IsVisible="False" />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

This snippet is at the beginning of each content page and it successfully disables the back button.

1 - However, this snippet runs after the page is loaded, hence the page first comes up with a back button and then it disappears when this code runs. It creates an unpleasant situation from a UX perspective. How can I disable the back button so that the page loads without one?

2 - Following on from above, can I disable back button globally for all pages ? I tried to put above code under AppShell.xaml, but it made no changes at all.

Comment: 1. If you want to hide or disable the back button when navigating to the target page in MAUI Shell app, you can use `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(WelcomePage)}");`, add `//`  in front of the route like `//route`,the matching page will replace the navigation stack.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#relative-routes. 2. I don't think you can do it globally. You can only put `Shell.BackButtonBehavior` in a `ContentPage` when using the Shell to navigate to other pages using `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(WelcomePage)}");`

Comment: Quick question, do you simply want the back button gone, or you want the user to not be able to go back?

Comment: Basically, I couldn't change the color of the back button, and couldn't consistently removed the bug where it duplicates page title on shorter titles, so decided to create my own navbar. It works fine but then I need to remove the old back button, and remove it in such a way that it doesn't get displayed on page load and removed a moment later.

Comment: If you wan tot change the color of the back button, you can use `IconOverride` to replace the default back button, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-6.0#back-button-behavior

Comment: Thanks Alexandar, I need to change the title color/font as well. Question was more about how can we change a shell behaviour without implementing it on every single page. I'd expect changes in AppShell.xml to be propagated but this is not the case.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you can't put code `Shell.BackButtonBehavior `under AppShell.xaml, it's used for `ContentPage`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-6.0#back-button-behavior